Is this bug in my regular expressions in RewriteRule or bug mod_rewrite?
I have the following skeleton of my pet project:
.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ files.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$  api.php?get=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      pages.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]

files.php
<?php
echo 'files:<br>';
var_dump($_GET);
// TODO: file generation implementation
?>

api.php
<?php
echo 'api:<br>';
var_dump($_GET);
// TODO: implementation of API commands
?>

pages.php
<?php
echo 'pages:<br>';
var_dump($_GET);
// TODO: routing and generation of html pages. page addresses can have different nesting
?>

My problem is that for any request the code from the pages.php file is executed.
POSSIBLY the solution to my problem is:
.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

index.php
<?php
switch (explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1])
{
    case 'file':
        require 'files.php';
        break;
    case 'api':
        require 'api.php';
        break;
    default:
        require 'pages.php';
        break;
}
?>

BUT I encountered some strange behavior of mod_rewrite when changing regular expressions. And I would like to understand this situation.
If I have the following regular expressions:
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ files.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$  api.php?get=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      pages.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]

For URL http://localhost/any_text_1/any_text_2/any_text_3 I have the correct result:
pages
array(1) { ["get"]=> string(32) "any_text_1/any_text_2/any_text_3" }

But for URL http://localhost/api/cmd1/param1 I have an incorrect result (control should have been transferred to the file api.php, not pages.php):
pages (NOTE: here I was expecting to get "api")
array(1) { ["get"]=> string(11) "cmd1/param1" }

BUT if I change the regular expressions (remove the "/" symbol):
RewriteRule ^file(.*)$ files.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$  api.php?get=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     pages.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]

Then I will get the result I need (except for one problem):
For URL http://localhost/any_text_1/any_text_2/any_text_3 I have the correct result (except for the extra "/" character in the parameter):
pages
array(1) { ["get"]=> string(32) "/any_text_1/any_text_2/any_text_3" }

And for URL http://localhost/api/cmd1/param1 I have the correct result (except for the extra "/" character in the parameter):
api
array(1) { ["get"]=> string(12) "/cmd1/param1" }

BUT the problem I talked about earlier is this:
For URL http://localhost/api11111/cm1/param1 I get the result:
api
array(1) { ["get"]=> string(16) "11111/cm1/param1" }

But this address should have processed the file pages.php, not api.php.
It turns out that regular expressions with the "/" symbol do not do routing. And regular expressions without the "/" symbol do routing, but it does it not quite correctly.
Why? Is this a bug in my regular expressions or in mod_rewrite?
P.S.: Sorry if my question is too long or poorly worded. Honestly, I tried to write better.


URL like http://localhost/file/1 matches the rule ^file/(.*)$ and the code from the files.php file should be executed. But the code from the pages.php file is executed. ... (In the code from the pages.php file, I get the correct value of the get parameter).

In a directory/.htaccess context the L flag simply terminates the current pass by the rewrite engine. It does not terminate all execution. A second pass then occurs, passing back the newly rewritten URL (eg. files.php?get=1 in this example).
Because the last rule matches everything, it catches the newly rewritten URL during the second pass by the rewrite engine and ends up rewriting the URL to pages.php?get=files.php&get=1 (the previously rewritten query string is appended because of the QSA flag). As far as PHP is concerned, the get param appears to be correct because the second instance overwrites the first (in the $_GET superglobal).
Your regex should be more specific. Do you really need to match everything in the last rule (and the first two rules for that matter)? Or is it only intended to match single path segments (and no dots) as in your example "news"?
If so, then make the regex more restrictive. For example:
:
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$      pages.php?get=$1 [QSA,L]

The regex ^([^/.]*)$ matches news, but not news/something or news.php.
And/Or on Apache 2.4 you can prevent the second pass by the rewrite engine by using the END flag instead of L in your rules.
However, if you don't make the regex more specific (or include additional conditions) then you are potentially going to rewrite your static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) as well, which is usually undesirable.

Aside:

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$  api.php?get=$1   [QSA,L]


For this rule to work you would need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled (otherwise mod_negotiation "rewrites" the request to api.php before this rule is processed and no get param is passed). MultiViews is disabled by default on Apache, however, some servers/distributions override this and enable it for some reason.
Basically, MultiViews enables extension-less file URLs to just "work". But this applies to everything, potentially results in duplicate content issues and can conflict with your mod_rewrite rules!
For example, at the top of your .htaccess file:
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews


Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I will rewrite my question in more detail.

I have rewritten my question completely. Please look at it.
